# keyboard pushes bottom elements upward

Tags: ios7, keyboard, ionic-framework

In my app when I select to give input to particular input field which positioned at top the keyboard pushes all my bottom element upward. I am using Ionic framework. In android platform it is solved by changing windowsoftinput to adjustpan from autoresize. How to solve this problem in case of ios platform.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to add the class `hide-on-keyboard-open` to the items you want to stay "behind the keyboard" you can read more about how this works [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170118135211/http://ionicframework.com:80/docs/api/page/keyboard/)
it involves using the [ionic keyboard plugin](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard)

Comment: is this usefull with cordova??

Comment: Yeah it should work fine. I would give it a go. If it doenst work let me know and I will try another fix for you.